Подключение тг бота на aiogram3 к Postgres БД в отдельном файле, используя asyncpg
У меня есть телеграм бот, он организован как проект, структурирован по папкам. Раньше я использовал библиотеку psycopg2 для работы с бд, но, насколько я понимаю, она не очень хорошо работает в ассинхронных ботах, поэтому перехожу на asyncpg.
Сложность в том, что я хочу организовать подключение к бд в отдельном файле. Мне нужно, чтобы при старте бота создавалось подключение к базе данных и conn, а дальше я мог импортировать этот conn в любой другой файл проекта и использовать его для запросов к бд. Я написал следующий код, и хотел бы посоветоваться с вами, насколько это оптимальное и рабочее решение?
файл postgres_db.py:
import asyncpg
import os


class DatabaseConnection:
    _conn = None

    @classmethod
    async def connect(cls):
        if cls._conn is None:
            try:
                cls._conn = await asyncpg.connect(os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL'))
                print('Data base connected OK!')
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Unable to connect to the database: {e}")

    @classmethod
    async def get_conn(cls):
        if cls._conn is None:
            await cls.connect()
        return cls._conn

открытие соединения с бд, main.py:
import asyncio
from data_base.postgres_db import DatabaseConnection
from handlers.echo import echo_router

from create_bot import bot, dp


dp.include_router(echo_router)

async def main():
    print("Бот вышел в онлайн!")
    await DatabaseConnection.connect()
    await bot.delete_webhook(drop_pending_updates=True)
    await dp.start_polling(bot)

asyncio.run(main())


Пример, как я импортирую conn в хендлерах:
from aiogram import Router, types
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart
from data_base.postgres_db import DatabaseConnection


echo_router = Router()


@echo_router.message(CommandStart())
async def show_statistic(message: types.Message):
    conn = await DatabaseConnection.get_conn()
    await conn.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM statistic')
    count_start = await conn.fetchval('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM statistic')
    await message.answer(f'Число пользователей, нажавших /start: {count_start}')
    

@echo_router.message()
async def echo_message(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(message.text)


Вы тестировали ваш код? если код рабочий, вы можете добавить метку [инспекция-кода] заменив одну из ваших меток

Я тестировал, если запустить бот сейчас локально, все работает. Но я не уверен, насколько корректно будет работать бот, когда он будет на сервере взаимодействовать с большим количеством пользователей. С psycopg2 часто бывало, что локально все ок, а в реальной работе соединение разрывалось. Поэтому я и пытаюсь понять, правильно ли я подключаю бд к боту. Метку поставил, спасибо!

Может Вам лучше использовать pool для  подключения к БД!? Это будет лучше, при обработке множества запросов одновременно. Посмотрите мой ответ.

@AnnaBazueva спасибо за ваш ответ! Единственное, хотел бы уточнить у вас, могу ли я отправлять sql запросы напрямую из хендлеров, находящихся в других файлах (относительно файла с базой данных) при использовании pool? То есть импортировать pool из файла с бд в хендлеры и отправлять там запросы с помощью async with self.pool.acquire() as connection:
Понимаю, что отправлять запросы напрямую из хендлеров - моветон. Но на данном этапе я бы хотел просто проверить корректность работы моего бота на asyncpg.

@Rezo Первое: "спасибо за ваш ответ!" –  если мой ответ был Вам полезен, то просто голосуйте за него, договорились!? ;) Второе: сам sql-запрос (например обновление данных пользователя) может быть полезен в нескольких хендлерах, т.е. прописывая один и тот же запрос в разных хендлерах – вы просто загромоздите код. проще прописать этот запрос один раз в методе Database. Третье: сейчас Ваш вопрос может быть закрыт как дубликат, поэтому попробуйте перестроить код под использование pool(а) и обновите свой вопрос (если возникнут сложности).
